# https detection - pros/cons to these two methods

Tags: php, html, http, https

I would like to have 'intelligent' detection of https/http for the resources I link within my pages.  Basically if the page needs a valid ssl, I can only put `https` href's.

**option 1 (using PHP)**

```
<?php
if ( $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] == "80" ) {
    $http = "http";
} else {
    $http = "https";
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=$http?>://myUri.com/script.js"></script>
```

**Option 2 (using** `//` **instead of** `http://` **OR** `https://`**)**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//myUri.com/script.js"></script>
```

**Option 3 use** `https` **for everything**
Is there any reason I shouldn't just use https for everything?

Comment: About "Is there any reason I shouldn't just use https for everything?" for one thing its much slower.

Answer (score 5):

The protocol-relative `//` is the most intuitive way of handling this.  I am not certain it is universally supported by older browsers, however.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//myUri.com/script.js"></script>
```

In PHP though, you should not check for `$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] == "80"`, as you may at some point need to run your web server on a port other than 80/443, in development for example.  Instead, check the contents of the `HTTPS` server variable:

```
if (isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) && $_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {}
```

Comment: Hmm, in June 1995 [rfc1808](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1808) was released. The browsers that time didn't even support virtual hosts, so ... :)

Comment: I often use this line to get my own absolute location (minus query string etc), and (under Apache and NginX at least) this works perfectly every time, including getting the right port: `$__SELF = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) != 'off') ? 'https' : 'http').'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];`. Note that I don't compare with $_SERVER['HTTPS'] with 'on', I test it as a boolean and make sure it's not 'off' - this is after 1 particular instance where it kept coming out with HTTPS when it shouldn't have been...

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: This isn't robust. It is unlikely that someone will do SSL over port 80, but it is possible.

Option 2: This is robust, simple and safe. Use it.

Option 3: If you use SSL for all your scripts, but not the pages then you will get Mixed Content alerts. Serving all your content over SSL will have implications for caching and performance (but is generally a good idea for any part of a site that needs the user to be logged in).